# Insert Nan into specific positions in a vector

Tags: python, list, vector, indexing, nan

I have two vectors called A and B: A is a list of numbers and B is a list that indicates the order that the numbers of A should be arranged.

I would like to create a vector C, where the numbers of vector A are arranged according to the positions laid out in vector B.

The numbers in A don't cover the entire range of possible positions in B, so I need to create a vector C with NaN or [] for missing A values. What is the fastest way of doing this?

See example below:

```
A = [5, 10, 55, 3, 10]
B = [1, 3, 4, 6, 9]
C = [5, nan, 10, 55, nan, 3, nan, nan, 10]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you restricted to base python or is numpy okay?

Comment: I think either your indices or your expected output are off (remember that indices start from `0`)

Comment: This looks like a homework question, and you haven't posted code of your own to attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer using numpy and avoiding "for"

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([5, 10, 55, 3, 10])
B = np.array([1, 3, 4, 6, 9])
#C = [5, nan, 10, 55, nan, 3, nan, nan, 10]

c = np.ones(B[-1])*np.NaN #create array of nans with desired length
c[B-1] = A #assing values (remember indices in python starts at 0)

print(c)
#[ 5. nan 10. 55. nan  3. nan nan 10.]
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
C = [A[B.index(i)] if i in B else nan for i in range(max(B) + 1)]
# [nan, 5, nan, 10, 55, nan, 3, nan, nan, 10]
```

or if you really want to skip index 0:

```
C = [A[B.index(i)] if i in B else nan for i in range(1, max(B) + 1)]
# [5, nan, 10, 55, nan, 3, nan, nan, 10]
```